# Unity Ar foundation body tracking. Is it possible to track multiple bodies?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, ar-foundation

If you use the latest version of AR foundation (I had to manually edit Packages/manifest.json to get it) and also have an *iphone* with an A12 processor or later, you can have body tracking.

You can track 3d or 2d human bodies.
I am interested in the 2d tracking.

In [Unity's demo](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples) they are using this line of code to get the human body data

```
var joints = m_HumanBodyManager.GetHumanBodyPose2DJoints(Allocator.Temp);
```

Which seems to only return info for one body even if the phone can see 2 or more.
I am wondering if tracking multiple bodies is possible, some functions of the [humanBodyManager class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@5.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARHumanBodyManager.html#UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARHumanBodyManager_OnTrackablesChanged_System_Collections_Generic_List_UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARHumanBody__System_Collections_Generic_List_UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARHumanBody__System_Collections_Generic_List_UnityEngine_XR_ARFoundation_ARHumanBody__) seem to hint at this being possible. eg.

This function

```
    OnTrackablesChanged(List<ARHumanBody>, List<ARHumanBody>, List<ARHumanBody>)

    List<ARHumanBody>   added   
    The list of human bodies added to the set of trackables.
    List<ARHumanBody>   updated            
    The list of human bodies updated in the set of trackables.
    List<ARHumanBody>   removed             
    The list of human bodies removed to the set of trackables.
```

and this event

```
public event Action<ARHumanBodiesChangedEventArgs> humanBodiesChanged

The event that is fired when a change to the detected human bodies is reported.
```

That function is protected, and I have tried subscribing to that event but it doesnt ever seem to be called. Its also very weird as its an event which wants to call functions which *return* an action that takes ARHumanBodiesChangedEventArgs as a paramater... I dunno why anyone would ever write a thing like that tbh.

Anyway writing visual debug code and then *building* to iOS to test all these semi documented classes is a massive pain. If someone could just let me know if multiple body tracking is even possible with ar foundation that would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about the body tracking but you misunderstood the `event Action<ARHumanBodiesChangedEventArgs> humanBodiesChanged` part: that is an event that needs a listener like this: `void Whatever(ARHumanBodiesChangedEventArgs args)`, not a method that returns anything.

Comment: @frankhermes I replied that that would be sane, but the actual code is not like that.. But then I had another look and it *is* actually sane.. Either last night I was tired or else VS and unity were having a shit attack as they often do. Tx!